# Mailarchiva Web Services

Tags: java, rest

I'm trying to use the Web Services API in MailArchiva. Using the example from the site, i'm doing:

```
 curl --header "Authorization: *REDACTED*" --header "Accept: application/xml" http://*REDACTED*:8090/api/blob?query=subject:test -k
```

However, instead of search results, I get:

```
 failed to search for blob:class javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity does not specify the type parameter T of GenericType<T>
```

Anyone have any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Version is 5.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in v5.3.4 released 15 November.

```
GenericEntity<SearchResultsREST> entity = new GenericEntity<SearchResultsREST>(rest) {};
```

was replaced with:

```
GenericEntity<SearchResultsREST> entity = new GenericEntity<SearchResultsREST>(rest,rest.getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
```

Comment: Version is 5.3.1. Thanks! (Also, where did you get the source, I've looked and couldn't find it)

Comment: The update worked perfectly. Search API works as documented now.